# Best way to use devexpress gridcontrol

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I'm using devexpress for a windows form project, i'm came from web developing (classical asp.net applications), and i need to know if what i doing is that right way. First of all, i'm using de gridcontrol to make a CRUD, but exists a better way to insert/delete rows? I'm using a List, to add/delete rows on it and update the datasource to the gridview.

Sorry for the poor english :)

Comment: The WinForms Data Grid (GridControl) provides rich capabilities to display, shape and edit data from any data source. You can choose between the following data presentation formats (Views) in the Data Grid.

Comment: Traditional tabular format (Grid View)
Banded tabular format (Banded Grid View and Advanced Banded Grid View).
Cards (Layout View and Card View)
Tiles (Tile View)
Windows Explorer-inspired style (WinExplorer View)
Data shaping capabilities include, but are not limited to sorting, grouping, summary calculation, cell merging, data editing, master-detail and split presentations, as well as a rich set of filtering and data searching options such as built-in column filters and Find Panel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The better way is strongly depends on your tasks. Anyway you can starts here:

- [XtraGrid Concepts](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument3458)
- [XtraGrid Examples](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument3000)

P.S. I suggest you use the [DevExpress Support Center](http://devexpress.com/Support/Center/) to get official and guaranteed assistance on the use of DevExpress products. Note that FULL SUPPORT IS FREE during the evaluation period (30 days)

Comment: DevExpress support forums rock! They really try to help you.

Comment: thanks dude... i'll read later this documentation :)

Answer (score -1):

The most accurate way to update data in this scenario is to use the GridView.RowUpdated event. Just handle this event and update only necessary rows. Is this approach useful for you? 
I am looking forward to your response.

https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q478681/best-way-to-update-a-gridview